# two functions Bitcoin has which are absent from Litecoin: `MakeTransactionRef()` and `std::move()`

Tags: bitcoin-core, litecoin

From the file `chainparams.cpp`...

#### Litecoin:

```
genesis.vtx.push_back(txNew);
```

#### Bitcoin:

```
genesis.vtx.push_back(MakeTransactionRef(std::move(txNew)));
```

---

What is this function `MakeTransactionRef()`?

What is the function `std::move()`?

Why does Bitcoin have them while Litecoin does not?

Can they be safely be ignored in a new altcoin?

More of the salient differences are highlighted [here](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/Bitcoin-vs-Litecoin/blob/master/README.md).